# c# asp.net MVC5 model can not insert 4 decimal points

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, database-design, model, asp.net-mvc-5

for example inserting **(0.1234)** by the manual query is fine but while using the mvc5 form to insert the value from the form.

1- configurations of column in database is :

```
    RateBuy (decimal(18, 4))
```

2- the model is setup like , while inserting the data from the from

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n4}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal RateBuy { get; set; }
```

result is **0.1200** in the database

3- the model is setup like, while inserting the data from the from

```
       [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.0000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

result is **0.1200** in the database

Code to save data :

```
 public ActionResult SaveNew(Rate tbl)
        {
            Rate t = new Rate ();
            t.RateBuy = tbl.RateBuy;
            dbConnection.Entry(t).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
            dbConnection.SaveChanges();
            return View();

        }
```

any solution a big head ache...

Comment: The code you have shown is not concerned with databases.

Comment: there is one update check please, but the database must support decimal too

Comment: Still no database related code.

Comment: here we required to have the decimal(18, 4) in database, in order to support 4 points

Comment: You have shown no code where the value is saved in a database.

Comment: Have you verified what `tbl.RateBuy` contains in `SaveNew`?

Comment: it's saving the data, in the database but the issue is not allowing 4 decimal place 
for example i insert 0.1234 and inside the database it gets 0.1200 and yes
i check it's 0.1234

Comment: If `tbl.RateBuy` is indeed 0.1234 in `SaveNew` when it executes, then check how your database model is set up and which data properties are assigned for that field.

Comment: yes, this is strange for me while debug i check the value is correct only after insert to database it's change to that. may be it's because of web.config or some other issue on the entityframework

Comment: So check what properties you have specified in EF for that column (which is different to the properties you have specified in the database). They should match.

Answer (score 0):

For this i have changed the decimal to float and use this in the model

```
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,4}$", ErrorMessage = "Rate can't have more than 4 decimal places")]
        public float RateBuy { get; set; }
```

Comment: Using `float` for money is going to [get you in trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/11683). Fix your `decimal` definition instead in the EF properties.